# Acumatica - Raise multiple error/Exception

Tags: acumatica

good day

I am trying to raise multiple errors at the same time.

Example:
When Acumatica finds errors during saving it will show all the errors at the same time:

[image]

Am trying to achieve the same on my Sale order grid:

```
    protected void SOLine_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
        //logic ...
        if (ShowError)
        {
            string errorMsg = "locationID error msg";
            // The error shows on SOLine.locationID
            cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOLine.locationID>(row, row.LocationID, new PXSetPropertyException(errorMsg, PXErrorLevel.Error));
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to raise the exception to achieve multiple errors to be raised at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError` method. It works in most context and doesn't throw an exception.

You can put many SetError/SetWarning calls in RowSelected method:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<DAC.field>(cache, row, "Error Message");
```

Or you can put a single one in multiple FieldValidating events.

Answer (score 0):

The FieldValidating event is an ideal place to add these messages.

Comment: True, I have a warning showing there and then this error as they save.

Comment: Im not sure I understand, your trying to get the same result as Acumatica in that an attempt to save flags up many error messages.